# how to get single field value in object list

Tags: object, filter, kotlin, field

how to get some field list in object list in **kotlin**

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){
    println("Hello World")
    val list = listOf(member("hong",10), member("kil", 10))
}

data class member(var name:String, var age:Int)
```

Above code, I want to get single field list in above code such as name

```
  {"hong", "kil"}
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You want to get list with only name field? If so, then use `map` (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html)

`val names = list.map { it.name }`

Comment: wow. It is simple solution and works very well. thanks.

Comment: man, do i really have to read through all the documentation to find this gem?